# C# Download File from FTP AS400

Tags: c#, batch-file, ftp, ibm-midrange

we currently have a *.BAT file that contains some FTP commands to download a file from our AS400 and save into a TEXT file. The BAT works fine and the text file will show the records inside the downloaded file one under the other.

Now, we wanted to get rid of this *.BAT file and use C# to download the file for us and save into a text file. The problem now is that the file we get contains all the records in ONE single line of string! they are no longer listed under each other.

here is the code we are using:

```
tpWebRequest request = default(FtpWebRequest);
        FtpWebResponse response = default(FtpWebResponse);
        StreamWriter writer = default(StreamWriter);

        request = WebRequest.Create("*******URL******") as FtpWebRequest;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.UseBinary = true;

        response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;

        writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("/filename.txt"));

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(37))) //37 for IBM encoding
        {
            writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }

        writer.Close();

        response.Close();
```

Any idea why we are getting this? and why the simple DOS FTP command work better than our code?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I think you should start by using the debugger and examine the value returned by `reader.ReadToEnd()`. The function preserves the new line characters (probably just LF or CR in the original file) while `ftp` translates them to CRLF when transferring in ASCII mode.

Comment: Use a hex editor to look at the actual output. It probably has CRs but no LFs or similar. You may need to do some string replacement to introduce them. The IBM encoding will fix the little/big endian mismatch, but I'm not sure about the CR/LF pairs.

Comment: Make sure it's writing the newline in the file. If it's not, try adding a newline manually. Also, notepad doesn't show newlines sometimes. Try WordPad or another editor.

Comment: I have a feeling that you might be up to something here. I have my doubts that it has something to do with line termination. I am sorry, what is Hex Editor? and how can I use it exactly to help me out in my situation ?

Comment: What type of file are you downloading? A database file has neither CR nor LF to delimit records; those must be added by the download process. What does the server see as the actual request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII mode will add record delimiters when downloading a physical file.  It is the default transfer mode of most ftp clients.

```
request.UseBinary = false;
```

> Specifying false causes the FtpWebRequest to send a "Type A" command to the server.

[Data Transfer Methods](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaiq/rzaiqfrmt.htm?lang=en-us)

[Transferring QSYS.LIB files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaiq/rzaiqreferencedt6.htm?lang=en)

Comment: man! you are the best! THAT WORKED! :)
I set the UseBinary to false. Also, I changed the Encoding for the StreamReader to ASCII and the file just got downloaded perfectly. I want to also thank all of you who have tried to help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be simple: you read the whole document at once. You need to read every line seperately:

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
     while(!sr.EndOfStream)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
     }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code and i keep getting the below error:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

Comment: At the sr.ReadLine() line?